# The constructor JSONobject(object) is not visible

Tags: json, processing

I'm trying to grab a JSON object for hex values but keep on getting the error The constructor JSONobject(object) is not visible. I'm using Processing version 2.1.

```java
String baseURL = "http://www.colr.org/json/tag/";
String[] keyword = {"county"};

void setup(){
getColor();
};

void draw(){
};

void getColor(){
  for (int i = 0; i < keyword.length; i++){
  String request = baseURL + keyword[i];

  try{
    JSONObject colorData = new JSONObject(join(loadStrings(request),""));
    JSONArray results = colorData.getJSONArray("results");
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
      println("error");
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all: you can't use that constructor.

You should just use the `loadJSONObject()` function instead. You can give it the url directly instead of going through the extra step of calling `loadStrings()` and then `join()` (which is a bit of a roundabout way to read a `String` anyway):

```
JSONObject colorData = loadJSONObject(request);
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/loadJSONObject_.html).